# Adding a row into DataFrame with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I would like to create a new DataFrame and a bunch of stock data per each date.

1. Declaring a DataFrame with a multi-index - date and stock ticker.
2. Adding data for 2020-06-07

   ```
           date        stock   open    high    low     close
           2020-06-07  AAPL   33.50    34.20   32.1    33.30
           2020-06-07  MSFT   53.50    54.20   32.1    53.30
   ```
3. Adding data for 2020-06-08

   ```
           date        stock   open    high    low     close
           2020-06-07  AAPL   33.50    34.20   32.1    33.30
           2020-06-07  MSFT   53.50    54.20   32.1    53.30
           2020-06-08  AAPL   32.50    34.20   31.1    32.30
           2020-06-08  MSFT   58.50    59.20   52.1    53.30
   ```

What would be the best and most efficient solution?

Here's my current version that doesn't work as I expect.

```
            df = pd.DataFrame()
            for date in dates:
                universe500 = get_universe(date) #returns stocks on a specific date
                for security in universe500:
                    prices = data.get_prices(security, ['open','high','low','close'], 1, '1d') # returns pd.DataFrame
                    df.iloc[(date, security),:] = prices
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimum reproducible example ?

Comment: where are you getting the data you are trying to add - from a CSV, from a website, are you entering it manually?  Is the data above in `pandas` or is that what you want to get?

Comment: To find the best and most efficient solution, we need to see the data and its source - json, API call, CSV, text file, etc. Please paste that.

Comment: I have added an example below.

Comment: @SyKer I added a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: @Tom I'm getting the data from Quantopian platform. I get open, high, low, close prices per each security and I would like to create a pandas dataframe containing all dates and securities. So, it will be a pandas df with multiindex.

Comment: @NYCCoder could you please look at the updates example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `prices` is a `DataFrame` formatted in the same manner as the original `df`, you can use `concat`:

```
In[0]:

#consttucting a fake entry
arrays = [['06-07-2020'], ['ABCD']]
multi = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=('date', 'stock'))
to_add = pd.DataFrame({'open':1, 'high':2, 'low':3, 'close':4},index=multi)
print(to_add)

Out[0]:
                  open  high  low  close
date       stock                        
2020-06-09 ABCD      1     2    3      4
```

```
In[1]:

#now adding to your data
df = pd.concat([df, to_add])
print(df)

Out[1]:
                  open  high   low  close
date       stock                         
2020-06-07 AAPL   33.5  34.2  32.1   33.3
           MSFT   53.5  54.2  32.1   53.3
2020-06-08 AAPL   32.5  34.2  31.1   32.3
           MSFT   58.5  59.2  52.1   53.3
2020-06-09 ABCD    1.0   2.0   3.0    4.0
```

If the data (`prices`) were just an array of 4 numbers (the open, high, low, and close) values, then `loc` would work in the place you used `iloc`:

```
In[2]:

df.loc[('2020-06-10','WXYZ'),:] = [10,20,30,40]

Out[2]:

                  open  high   low  close
date       stock                         
2020-06-07 AAPL   33.5  34.2  32.1   33.3
           MSFT   53.5  54.2  32.1   53.3
2020-06-08 AAPL   32.5  34.2  31.1   32.3
           MSFT   58.5  59.2  52.1   53.3
2020-06-09 ABCD    1.0   2.0   3.0    4.0
2020-06-10 WXYZ   10.0  20.0  30.0   40.0
```